# Python TF ObjectDetection! object_detection not found

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I got the well known ImportError: No module named 'object_detection'
I added my **./research and my ./research/slim folders to my .~bashrc. When I run the builder/optimize_builder_test.py it works. If I run my modified detection I get the error. Here is a current screenshot from my .bashrc file [image]

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Just a wrong placed spacebar
[image]

Just a wrong placed spacebar